# Can't run test on spring boot application because of injection of persistence dependencies failed

Tags: java, unit-testing, spring-boot, junit, spring-data-jpa

I have my java spring boot application and I'd like to write some tests using mockmvc; so this is the testing class:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(controllers = {IndexController.class})
@ComponentScan(basePackages={"com.sherlock.discoteque"})
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.sherlock.discoteque.repository")
@EntityScan(basePackages={"com.sherlock.discoteque"})
public class DiscotequeApplicationTests {

private MockMvc mockMvc;

@Autowired
private WebApplicationContext webApplicationContext;

@Before
public void setup() {
    this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(webApplicationContext).build();
}

@Test
public void testAlbumInfo() throws Exception{
   this.mockMvc.perform(get("/")).andExpect(status().isOk());
}
```

}

but when I execute the code I have the following error message:

> Field albumRepository in com.sherlock.discoteque.controller.AlbumController required a bean of type 'javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory' that could not be found.
>
> The injection point has the following annotations:
>     - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)
>
> Action:
>
> Consider defining a bean of type
>   'javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory' in your configuration.
>   ...
>   Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: 
>   Error creating bean with name 'albumController': Unsatisfied
>   dependency expressed through field 'albumRepository'; nested exception
>   is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: **Error
>   creating bean with name 'albumRepositoryImpl': Injection of
>   persistence dependencies failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException**: No
>   qualifying bean of type 'javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory'
>   available
>   Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
>   Error **creating bean with name 'albumRepositoryImpl': Injection of
>   persistence dependencies failed;** nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
>   qualifying bean of type 'javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory'
>   available

Which is weird, considering the fact that without the testing class everything works fine. This is the class AlbumRepositoryImpl

```
public class AlbumRepositoryImpl implements AlbumRepositoryCustom {

private final static String RECENT_ALBUMS_QUERY = "select * from album order by createdate desc limit ?";

@PersistenceContext
public EntityManager entityManager;

@Override
public List<Album> getRecentAlbums(int size) {
    if(size<1){
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }
    Query query = entityManager.createNativeQuery(RECENT_ALBUMS_QUERY, Album.class);
    query.setParameter(1, size);
    return query.getResultList();
}
}
```

and inside the AlbumController I do have the attribute

```
   @Autowired
private AlbumRepository albumRepository;
```

and I have the AlbumRepository interface as well (extended from JpaRepository). I really don't know what to do to make the web application running on test, could anybody help me?

Answer (score 1):

In sample code , you are trying to autowire the context , however you have not provided the test configuration.

In your project you have defined JPA entity manager configuration , but in test file you are not providing that info. Spring won't be able to start the container till you don't provide the necessary configuration in test class.

You can take an idea from https://www.petrikainulainen.net/programming/spring-framework/integration-testing-of-spring-mvc-applications-configuration/

Answer (score 0):

Try to set spring boot profile with annotation - @ActiveProfiles("you_profile")